# Make link non clickable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which i've seen online and trying to implement it.
What i'm trying to do is to make all the links with the parent class non clickable, i mean, it should click but not redirect to the page's link.

This won't work..

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.parent').click(function(){
                return false; // prevents default action
            });
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Try putting `e` as the argument to the callback then do `e.preventDefault()` in the body of the callback.

Comment: This is jQuery code, does your page have a link to jQuery? (e.g. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: An aside, but your selector of `.parent` will match all elements with a class of `parent`. Since you want to attach this behaviour to links with this class, you could change this to `a.parent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parent').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You don't need `$(window).load(function(){` because `$(document).ready(function(){` is the same thing!

**Later Edit:** I have to complete this answer by telling you that the code I wrote is using jQuery library, which must be included in your project. For more info about jQuery please visit http://jquery.com/

Comment: This works fine, my only issue is that the subpages of this link will also become not clickable..

Answer (score 0):

you need `event.preventDefault`

```
function unclickable(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Alternatively `return false;`

```
function unclickable() {
    return false;
}
```

and use it like:

```
<a class="parent" onclick="unclickable(event);">Link</a>
```